# How to make only one target BuildInParallel?

Tags: msbuild

I am having a target which will build then checkin the assemblies.

```
<Target Name="CoreBuildCheckinSubSystem" DependsOnTargets="BuildDotNETSolutions;CheckinSubSystemDos">


 </Target>
```

In this builddotnetSolution will build the list of solution in an order. So i do not want it to be buildinParallel but the CheckinSubsystemDos will checkin all the dlls. If the checkin process is being done in parallel it would save time for me.

How to make CheckinSubSystemDos alone in BuildInParallel?

Comment: Build in parallel with what? Your pipeline is sequential and non parallel. MS Build will execute BuildDotNETSolutions then CheckinSubSystemDos then CoreBuildCheckinSubSystem. You will need to provide a more concrete example for someone to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note about MSBuild, is that parallelization is done on the level of project. Targets within the same project are always executed sequentially, while two different project might (or might not) be executed in parallel. To rephrase it another way, if you want MSBuild to execute something concurrently, you have to create multiple projects and invoke them within the same `<MSBuild>` task.

In your case, the code would look like this. You have a list of projects or solutions to build:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyProjects Include="One.proj"/>
  <MyProjects Include="Two.proj"/>
  <MyProjects Include="Three.proj"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The build target would invoke `<MSBuild>` target sequentially:

```
<Target Name="BuildDotNETSolutions" ...>
  <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjects)" Targets="Build" BuildInParallel="false" />
</Target>
```

Your checkin target would invoke another target that is defined in the same projects -- call it `MyCheckin`:

```
<Target Name="CoreBuildCheckinSubSystem" DependsOnTargets="BuildDotNETSolutions;CheckinSubSystemDos">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjects)" Targets="MyCheckin" BuildInParallel="true" />
</Target>
```

Another option for you is to create a sibling set of projects -- call it `MyCheckinProjects` and use them in you checkin target:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyCheckinProjects Include="Checkin_One.proj"/>
  <MyCheckinProjects Include="Checkin_Two.proj"/>
  <MyCheckinProjects Include="Checkin_Three.proj"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

However I would suggest simply inserting a new target into existing projects.